# Unable to Transfer File from one pc to another using networking in JAVA

Tags: java, file, networking, transfer

I am trying to send file from one client 1 to another Client 2 using an intermediate server. Both Client 1 and Client 2 are connected to server through network.For this, I have given IP-address of server to both clients. 
But I am unable to transfer the file properly due to some mistake in my code. I am using the following code and its not working and at the Client 2 (receiver's) end, the file which is created is empty. 
Kindly find the possible error in my code.

### Server code

```
`
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class S1 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

try{

ServerSocket sc1=new ServerSocket(6988);
Socket c1=sc1.accept();
Socket c2=sc1.accept();



DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(c1.getInputStream());
int m=c1.getInputStream().available();
byte b2[]=new byte[m];
dis.read(b2);

DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(c2.getOutputStream());
dos.write(b2);
dos.flush();
dos.close();


}
catch(Exception e){}
}
}
```

---

### Client 1 (Sender)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class C11 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Socket c2=new Socket("127.0.0.1",6988);
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("f:/abc.jpg");
        File f1=new File("f:/abc.jpg");
        long l1=f1.length();
        int a=(int)l1;
        byte b1[]=new byte[a];
        DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(fis);
        dis.read(b1);
        DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(c2.getOutputStream());
        dout.write(b1);

    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    }

}
```

---

### Client 2 (Receiver)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class C22 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Socket c2=new Socket("127.0.0.1",6988);
        DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(c2.getInputStream());
        int m=c2.getInputStream().available();
        byte b2[]=new byte[m];
        dis.read(b2);
        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("E:\\PRACTICE\\xyz.txt");
        DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(fout);
        dos.write(b2);
        dos.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @Rahul No, but the code is not working as per my requirement.

Comment: You have no idea whether you're getting an error or not, because you ignore any exceptions. At the very least call `e.printStackTrace()` within all of those `catch` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Usual problems.

```
nt m=c1.getInputStream().available();
byte b2[]=new byte[m];
```

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29): "It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream."

```
dis.read(b2);
```

The `read()` method returns a value. You are ignoring it. The value can be -1, or a postive number between 1 and the buffer size. You're assuming the read filled the buffer. It isn't obliged to do that.

```
dout.write(b1);
```

That should be

```
dout.write(b1, 0, count);
```

where `count` was the length returned by `read(),` and it should be in a loop:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Use this at both ends, with any buffer size greater than zero. I usually use 8192.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious mistake is here:

```
 int m=c2.getInputStream().available();
```

The `available` method only tells you how much data can be read *without blocking*, not how much data could potentially be read from the socket. To read all of the data that was sent you need to write a loop that reads from the socket until `read` returns -1.